# How to post request python method from react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fetch-api, erpnext, frappe

I have a python method called `def login_device(data):`
I tried to post request using fetch api with react native but i always get an error status of 500
and an error message of `login_device() missing 1 required positional argument: 'data'`

here is my fetch request

```
fetch(
    "url/login_device",
    {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            loginData: credentials,
        }),
    },
)
```

as you can see i already pass the data in the body
but i always received an error login_device() missing 1 required positional argument: 'data'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your function is defined as :
def login_device(data):

It is expecting data as a parameter in the query string.since you are using POST method you can redefine your function as

def login_device():
data =json.loads(frappe.request.data)
Here data will be a dictionary and you can access that